# C++ delete[] failing only in release version

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2017, free, delete-operator

I am going through strange behavior. I have below piece of code which is crashing **(only in release mode)** during call to **delete[] pOutputStr** statement.

```
void MyFunction()

{

char* pOutputStr = new char[100];

//my other code which is nowhere related to this

delete[] pOutputStr; **// here its failing**

pOutputStr = NULL;

}
```

**Please note:** When I tried to debug in release mode, I noticed that code flow is going to debug mode. Refer below code:

```
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept

{
    #ifdef _DEBUG

    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK); // my code comes here instead of else block which is release mode

    #else

    free(block); // ideally it should come here, since its release mode.

    #endif

}
```

I suspected that somewhere in my code _DEBUG is defined, but that was not the case. Also I checked pre-processor section of project properties, there also I can see NDEBUG is defined.

Can you please let me know, what could be the issue?

**This issue was seen after migrating my code from VS2012 to VS2017 version.**

Kindly let me know what is missing here?

Comment: The problem is most likely in your "other code which is nowhere related to this". Perhaps you go out of bounds? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: `delete[]` always fails as the result of previously undiscovered undefined behavior. This behavior may not cause visible problems in debug version, but it's still there. Run your program through a memory profiler to see the issue.

Comment: Please give us a complete, self-contained program that replicates the behavior. If you find you cannot replicate the behavior without the code that you say is "nowhere related to this", doesn't that show that it is in fact related?

Comment: pOutputStr is a stack variable, and the 'rest of the code' likely manipulates things adjacent to it. A simple out of bounds write by this code could easily corrupt pOutputStr - meaning deleting it becomes impossible.

Look at this other code. Carefully.

Comment: Have you moved pOutputStr? You can only delete, if it is yet pointing to the array position you received via new!

Comment: I agree with all you guys, when I said “//my other code which is nowhere related to this” it means -  it’s my internal logic where I am doing some other core operations.

Now for sake of testing I did this which one also failed in similar fashion:

int* pInter = new int[2];

if (pInter != NULL)

{

delete[] pInter; // Crash

 pInter = NULL;

}

Now this is plane code without any other logic, but still I am getting same issue. Code goes to debug mode only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _When I tried to debug in release mode, I noticed that code flow is going to debug mode._ This is very odd and it may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: If you actually comment out "my other code which is nowhere related to this", does the problem go away?

Comment: @Michaeal even I feel thats the root cause. But not sure why it went to debug mode?

Comment: @Keith.. Yes, I tried that as well. But no luck

Comment: Another thought, just because `NDEBUG` is defined, doesn't mean `_DEBUG` will not be defined. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: is there any way that - I can remove `_DEBUG` if `NDEBUG` is defined?

Comment: In MSVC _DEBUG is defined by compiling in Debug or Release mode usually. You could manually #undef _DEBUG, but where are you going to put that? You won't know which header is screwing around. I would hard code `free(pOutputStr)` instead of `delete[] pOutputStr` and see if that fixes it. If it does you've got your work cut out for you tracking down some screwy #defines so that the correct code is compiled without hackery.

Comment: @keith Doing `free` on memory allocated with `new[]` is generally a bad idea, and one that leads to *undefined behavior*. The problem is in the code we can not see. And since we can not see it then it makes no point in guessing wildly. That's why I http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: @Some programmer dude, I completely agree, I'm not suggesting it as a permanent fix, I think that's clear from my comment.

Comment: You're entering the `_DEBUG` code because you're linking with a debug build of the runtime library. It has nothing to do with your code, and it's not a problem. It's very likely crashing in release because you forgot to intialise a variable somewhere, and that variable was zero-initialised in the debug build. Unfortunately for you, that variable can be pretty much anywhere.

Comment: @molbdnilo Usually Visual studio doesn't link release and debug libs. How could this error be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If stepping through the Release code, gets into the `_DEBUG` branch:

```
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept 
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG

    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK); // my code comes here instead of else block which is release mode

    #else
    //...
 }
```

that means that somewhere in your code you have:

```
#define _DEBUG
```

or something similar.

First check in the project compiler settings if `_Debug` is defined.

I usually then go out of the IDE, and hit my "commander" app and search the whole folder with my project for a file which contains the text `#define _DEBUG`.

This file/s is your culprit.

Comment: Nowhere in my entire solution directory '_DEBUG' is defined.

@Robert I checked if `_DEBUG` is defined using below code.

#ifdef _DEBUG
 
 MessageBox(NULL, L"Debug", L"Debug", MB_OK);
#else  

  MessageBox(NULL, L"Release", L"Release", MB_OK);

#endif // NDEBUG

Here I could see "Release" message. This is expected behavior.
Next line I wrote below code.
int* pInter = new int[2];

if (pInter != NULL)

{

 delete[] pInter; // After debugging inside I could see, it still hits '_DEBUG' section.

}

now I am not sure, What is missing here.

Comment: Then maybe @molbdnilo is correct, and you are linking release builds with debug builds.

Comment: I removed few memory related warnings due to which this issue is resolved.

Comment: @Tausif It would help others if You could post what helped.

Comment: in my code there were many variables which were declared but not used, also there were memory leakages in few places. I fixed those memory issues.